# Query that reports the customers with the total purchases strictly increasing

Tags: mysql, sql

In an interview I have been asked to return the **SQL query that reports the IDs of customers with the total purchases strictly increasing yearly**

Table is something like below:

[image]

And the output expected is `11,22` as `33` is not strictly increasing.

I did not able to solve it however, on googling I found the solution which is:

```
WITH year_cte AS (
    SELECT  customer_id, 
            YEAR(order_date) AS year, 
            SUM(price) AS total 
    FROM Orders
    GROUP BY customer_id, year
    ORDER BY NULL
)

SELECT a.customer_id
FROM year_cte a 
     LEFT JOIN year_cte b
     ON b.customer_id = a.customer_id AND b.year = a.year + 1
GROUP BY a.customer_id
HAVING SUM(a.total >= IFNULL(b.total, 0)) = 1 // Did not get this SUM
ORDER BY NULL;
```

Now my problem is that I am able to understand the solution apart from **1 line** which is:

```
HAVING SUM(a.total >= IFNULL(b.total, 0)) = 1 // Did not get this SUM
```

Can someone please help me to understand why there is a condition inside the `sum()` and why it is equating with `1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `a` table contains the `total` price for a `customer_id` for the year prior to table `b`.

You want to retrieve all `customer_id`s having `total` strictly increasing so you need to check that the number of rows satisfying the condition `a.total >= IFNULL(b.total, 0)` are `1`.

This case happens when the customer has a strictly increasing streak of `total`s during the years, the `= 1` accounts for the fact that the last line will have a value of `b.total` equal to `NULL` (and so `a.total >= 0` will satisfy the condition).

Using `customer_id = 11` as an example:

```
customer_id | year | total 
--------------------------
         11 | 2019 |   150
         11 | 2020 |   200
         11 | 2021 |   250
```

For `a.year = 2019` and `b.year = 2020` you will have `150 >= 200`.
For `a.year = 2020` and `b.year = 2021` you will have `200 >= 250`.
For `a.year = 2021` and `b.year = 2022` you will have `250 >= 0`.

The `SUM` of this expression will give `1`.

Comment: Thanks, but one thing I need to uderstand here is why the sum of expressions  200 >= 25 .... will give 1. Going by this you are saying that sum(true) = 1.

Comment: in MySQL `SUM(TRUE) = 1` and `SUM(FALSE) = 0`. The expression is counting how many of those comparisons are valid.